# Redshift last_value to retrieve the most current row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, query-performance

Below is one simple way to get the most recent version of a row.   While this works ‘okay’ for a single row, it does slow down when each row needs to be evaluated.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dev.A t1 
where to_char(last_operation_date,'yyyymmdd') = (select max(to_char(last_operation_date,'yyyymmdd')) 
                                                 from dev.A t2 
                                                 where t1.inte_id = t2.inte_id)
and t1.inte_id = 'PPP2434'
```

Comment: What data type is `last_operation_date`?

Comment: timestamp ex- '2017-12-13 22:12:56'

Comment: Based on your requirement "the most recent version" I think you query is wrong to begin with by ignoring the time part of the timestamp. Your query returns all rows that occurred on the most recent day, not one single "most recent version".

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to get from this query... do you need the last row for every `inte_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function to find the latest row per `inte_id` without using a correlated subquery. Correlated subqueries often require a nested loops step which slows them down.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY inte_id ORDER BY last_operation_date DESC ) last_op_order
    FROM dev.A t1 
    and t1.inte_id = 'PPP2434'
    )
WHERE last_op_order = 1;
```